# Как переместить блок из 1 столбца в другой

Tags: jquery

Как переместить блок из 1 столбца в другой и показать в какой столбец перенесли

Пробовал сделать с помощью Draggable, но не получаеться сделать перемещение между столбцами

- Как сделать, чтобы блоки нельзя было перетаскивать между собой? только по столбцам

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true,
      stop: function( event, div ) {}
    });
  } );
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
.sortable {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sortable">
    Столбец 1
    <div class="block">
      Блок1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sortable">
    Столбец 2
    <div class="block">
      Блок11
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок12
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок13
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать таким образом

```js
$( function() {

  $('.block').draggable({revert: true,zIndex: 100,revertDuration: 0,helper: "clone"});
  
  $( ".sortable" ).droppable({
    accept: ".block",
    over: function( event, ui )//если фигура над клеткой- выделяем её границей
    {
      $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    out: function( event, ui )//если фигура ушла- снимаем границу
    {
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    },
    drop:function( event, ui )//если бросили фигуру в клетку
    {
      if($(ui.draggable).parent().data('block') != $(this).data('block')) {//Проверяем блок остался в своем столбце или переместился, чтобы блок нельзя было таскать по своему столбцу
        $(this).prepend(ui.draggable);//перемещаем фигуру в нового предка
        alert('Блок перемещен в '+$(this).data('block')+' столбец');
      } else {
        alert('Блок остался на своем месте');
      }
    $(this).removeClass('hover');//убираем выделение
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
.sortable.hover {
  background: #cac3c3;
}
.sortable {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 25px 5px 5px;
}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div class="content">
  <div class="sortable" data-block="1">
    <div class="title">Столбец 1</div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sortable" data-block="2">
    <div class="title">Столбец 2</div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок11
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок12
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок13
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```