# Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь подключить `jquery-ui` в 'VUE' для использования `draggable`

[Проверка работы draggable на версии jq 1.12 и jq-ui - 1.12](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906289/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-1-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Установил `jquery` - 1.12.4 и `jquery-ui` - 1.12.1

```
npm install --save jquery jquery-ui
```

Подключаю `jq-ui`

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery-ui');
```

И получаю ошибку

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined"

found in

---> <CardComponent> at resources/js/components/CardComponent.vue
       <Root>
```

Пытался пойти простым путем -

Просто в `<head>` добавить

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Но он не видит `draggable`

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function"
```

Может есть более простой способ подключить `draggable` во VUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать [vuedraggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable) для этих целей.
Подключается достаточно просто

1 В компоненте импортируете модуль:

```
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
```

2 подключаете импортированный компонент

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  components: {
    draggable,
}
```

......

3 Необходимые элементы оборачиваете директивой

```
<draggable @start="drag=true" v-model="someModelName" @end="drag=false">
   <p>One</p>
   <p>Two</p>
   <p>Three</p>
</draggable>
```